# Move files from all sub folders to one sub folder within the directory recursively

Tags: powershell

How do I move all files from subfolders to one subfolder within the same directory recursively?
Ex:
Main folder:

```
Subfolder A
Subfolder A1
Subfolder A2
Subfolder A3

Subfolder B
Subfolder B1 
Subfolder B2
Sbufolder B3
```

I would like to run Powershell in Main folder and move files from Sub folders A1 & A2 to A3. Sub folders B1&B2 to B3 etc.

Edit:
Subfolders A1, A2, B1 ,B2 do have subfolders, which again have more subfolders.
I want to move just the files from these paths and not the folders.
I don't actually want to move files from all these paths. Just one type of subfolder within A1,A2, B1, B2... recursively.

I have  used the following code within A1, A2, B1, B2 to move files to A3, B3

Get-ChildItem -Path ".*" -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination "C:\Main folder\Subfolder A`\Subfolder A3"

I was hoping  for a code to do this for all subfolders A, B, etc simultaneously.

Edit 2:
I have tried the following code as well, but nothing happens

dir -filter "20" -directory -recurse |
ForEach-Object {
$Dest = "$($_.DirectoryName)\Plantegninger"

Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $Dest  }
So I want to move all files from folders which include 20 in its name
to a folder named Plantegninger.
I want to do this recursively within the main folder

Comment: Check out [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please explain. Do subfolders A1 and A2 have subfolders of their own too? Should they be moved to A3 aswell? or do you mean to move subfolders A1 and A2 as a whole to A3? Edit your question please and [1] show us the code you have already tried [2] explain what happens if you run that and [3] provide an example of the desired result